Get the scheduled timestamp of a team city queued build through API
I was asked to implement a notification system in our application to notify the users when the application is planned to be updated (and active users might be impacted).
Our builds are being done by Team City.
We've agreed that we would schedule every build and then use the API to get the scheduled builds and use that data to notify the user.
To test the API, I've scheduled a build a bit ahead of time:

However, I can't find anything in the API documentation to get the scheduled date, marked in yellow on the screenthot.
I'm using the http://%serveraddress%/app/rest/buildQueue?fields=build(id,buildTypeId,queuedDate,startDate,branchName,state) endpoint to get the needed information, the result is as followed:
<builds>
<build id="%ID%" buildTypeId="%Type%" state="queued" branchName="<default>">
<queuedDate>20240619T123859+0200</queuedDate>
</build>
</builds>

It doesn't contain the scheduled date, the queuedDate property is the time I've added it to the queue. The properties startDate and finishedDate are the only other 2 dates I could find in the documentation, but those only get a value when the build effectively starts & finishes.
Anyone any idea what field key I need to send to get the scheduled date?
I've tried "scheduledDate","scheduleDate","scheduled"
